# What Unicode symbol represents a person?

Tags: unicode, symbols

Does there exist a Unicode symbol that represents a person? I would expect something like this:

[image: pictogram of a stick figure]

I need a short way to represent a *price per person*, such as “25€/person”, but with the word “person” replaced with a Unicode character for a person. The benefit will be that the picture isn’t tied to the English language.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Just think of the [Emoji block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Blocks) of Unicode. Perhaps the man  at `U+1F468` or the woman  at `U+1F469` will suffice, but there are also children, older people, etc. Here’s a [list of Emoji People](http://emojipedia.org/people/). It still depends on your actual use-case.

If other exotics are no issue, take a look at [Egyptian Hieroglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_%28Unicode_block%29). There are lots of human pictograms, like  at `U+13020` and many others. Another generic (even gender-neutral) pictogram might be the symbol for men’s restrooms  at `U+1F6B9`, but a charge for restroom use is not desirable. There’s still more, like the pedestrian  at `U+1F6B6` or the bust in silhouette  at `U+1F464`.

As comprehensive, yet extensible list:

- `U+1F464` `BUST IN SILHOUETTE` (Block [Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs))
- `U+1F468` `MAN` (Block [Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Symbols_and_Pictographs))
- `U+1F6B9` `MENS SYMBOL` (Block [Transport and Map Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_and_Map_Symbols))
- `U+1F6B6` `PEDESTRIAN` (Block [Transport and Map Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_and_Map_Symbols))
- 웃 `U+C6C3` `HANGUL SYLLABLE US` (Block [Hangul Syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul_Syllables))
- ꆜ `U+A19C` `YI SYLLABLE HLIE` (Block [Yi Syllables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yi_Syllables))
- ጰ `U+1330` `ETHIOPIC SYLLABLE PHA` (Block [Ethiopic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopic_%28Unicode_block%29))
- `U+13020` `EGYPTIAN HIEROGLYPH A028` (Block [Egyptian Hieroglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_%28Unicode_block%29))

*(Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or off-site styling to distinguish details.)*

Depending on platform, the characters might be rendered surprisingly unresembling:

[image: Screenshots of the “person” pictographs above on different platforms.]

Comment: After this answer was written, in 2017,  (`U+1F9D1 ADULT`) was added to Unicode.

Answer (score 12):

This Korean character `U+c6c3 HANGUL SYLLABLE US`, looks a bit like your stick figure:

## **`웃`**

Since it's Korean for "smiling", you just may have to watch out for Koreans getting offended that they're being charged for what should, after all, be common courtesy on your part :-)

---

`웃, UTF-16: C6 C3`

`웃, UTF-8: EC 9B 83`

Comment: That *does* look like the OP’s image, while it does not maintain any semantic relevance (which might be OK). Google Translate translates 웃 to “smiling”.

Answer (score 11):

This is what the internet gods invented SVG for:

```css
svg {
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  stroke-width:10;
  stroke:black;
  fill:transparent;
}
```

```html
25€/<svg viewbox="0 0 150 300">
  <circle cx="75" cy="55" r="50" />
  <path d="M75,105 L75,200 L25,300 M75,200 L125,300 M0,150 L150,150"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: There’s actually plenty of other reasons why SVG was invented, but that’s a very good-looking application, even ready-to-use in HTML.

Comment: That's pretty nifty, had a play with it to get it to render 25€/person, hope you don't mind the change. In any case, I'll have to add that inline SVG stuff to my toolbox. Plus one for educating me.

Comment: This is probable the best option if you need a new symbol!! But imagine that you just want to cut and paste...

Comment: Unfortunately the email gods don't get along with the internet gods.

Comment: Worth mentioning that this solution (in the current format) is terrible for accessibility. There is no alternative text to the SVG image, so screen readers (or web crawlers) will only read "€25 slash", which is incomplete and makes no sense. (well, using random Unicode characters it not much better, anyway)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, there is a *stick man* (and *stick lady*) character:

[image: stick man]
[image: stick lady]

These characters are available from Unicode v13, therefore many systems are not capable to display it yet.

Source: http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1FB00.pdf

Comment: Funny … U+1FBC9 is a STICK FIGURE WITH DRESS. 

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on OSX / Firefox combination.